# Strange and Rare ArgumentOutOfRangeException on first line of Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception

I have a user control that works fine most of the time for thousands of requests, but usually about once or twice a day, there is an ArgumentOutOfRangeException that points to the first line of the Page_Load method within the code-behind of the aspx.vb file. I have never been able to replicate it myself, but I log the details/stack trace of the error.  The thing is, I am positive the error is not actually happening in Page_Load block, although the stack trace indicates otherwise.  In fact it does not matter what code I have in there, to prove this I put some dummy code in Page_Load, published and waited for the next occurrence as follows...

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim abc As Integer = 123
        abc = abc + 1
        ...
    End Sub
```

Sure enough, when the error eventually happened again, it still pointed to the first line of Page_Load (Line 16: Dim abc As Integer = 123).  Obviously this isn't the type of statement that would generate an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

```
Type: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
Source: mscorlib
TargetSite: Void ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
StackTrace:    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
at aut.ProductWithColorChoice.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Visual Studio Projects\1003\templates\usercontrols\ProductWithColorChoice.ascx.vb:line 16
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The only in-line code in use on the .ascx page is actually found in the javascript block to get the ClientId of controls in an effort to disable controls until the page is fully loaded.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="aut.ProductWithColorChoice" %>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    Sys.Application.add_load(setupButtonDisablers);
    function setupButtonDisablers() {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(onPageLoad);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(onSubmit);
        Sys.Application.remove_load(setupButtonDisablers);
    }
    function onPageLoad() {
        findAndEnable('<%= AddToCartImageButton.ClientID %>');
    }
    function onSubmit() {
        findAndDisable('<%= YearDropDownList.ClientID %>');
        findAndDisable('<%= MakeDropDownList.ClientID %>');
        findAndDisable('<%= ModelDropDownList.ClientID %>');
        findAndDisable('<%= ColorDropDownList.ClientID %>');
        findAndDisable('<%= AddToCartImageButton.ClientID %>');
    }
    function findAndDisable(id) { findAndSetDisabledProperty(id, true); }
    function findAndEnable(id) { findAndSetDisabledProperty(id, false); }
    function findAndSetDisabledProperty(id, value) {
        var control = $get(id);
        if (control) control.disabled = value;
        else alert('could not find ' + id);
    }
})();
</script>
```

I have gathered through logging that this error always happens on a postback likely fired via the autopostback event of a data bound drop down list.

One other thing to mention just in case it is relevant is that this control inherits another class called ProductControlBase, which then inherits UserControl.  I would think however, if the error was actually occurring there, that the stack trace would indicate that.

I have been stumped with this problem for a long time and would appreciate some insight on what could be causing that exception, or some suggestions on how to obtain more debugging info on the problem (although I can't directly replicate it).

**Update 12/7/12**
I haven't solved it yet, but have made progress.  Figured out that the stack trace is not pointing to the correct line in code, probably due to compiler optimizations, the error is probably a few lines down in this block... considering the check in the if statement, can you see any possibility that sizeIndex would not be in the range 0 - 6?  Note: PaintSizes, RegularPaintPrices and PaintWeights are all Specialized.StringCollections with 7 strings in each.

```
    If My.Settings.PaintSizes.Contains(SizeOption) Then
        sizeIndex = My.Settings.PaintSizes.IndexOf(SizeOption)            
        Price = Decimal.Parse(My.Settings.RegularPaintPrices(sizeIndex))
        Weight = Double.Parse(My.Settings.PaintWeights(sizeIndex))
    Else
        Throw New ApplicationException(Me.ID & ": sizeoption must match exactly one of the values in PaintSizes located in the web.config file")
    End If
```

Comment: Are you setting the selected value of dropdown list somewhere in Page_Lode or likely event?

Comment: Actually don't think it is related to dropdownlists as that has a different error message: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'DropDownList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items."

The error I'm getting is "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."